# Need some modeling/workflow tips on Kettlebell/grenade look

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to model this[image] with a physical surface(as opposed to just texturing/bump mapping etc) like this[image: fraggrenade]

Thanks! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really would recommend using a normal map since the detail is so small. You're going to have to have a huge number of vertices to get it to look decent.

If you're sure you need to be modeled, you'll probably want to use a displacement modifier:

[image: result]

Here's the modifier stack:

[image: modifiers]

And the texture settings:

[image: texture settings]

Comment: I think he's talking about putting the  rough extruded square things from the grenade onto the kettleball

Comment: @jacob no problem :) If it answers your question, could you mark it as an accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesL, how can I show a screenshot(already saved) of my model in this comment section?

Comment: @jacob the comments don't have image hosting built in, but you could upload to a site like http://imgur.com/ and paste the link.